# Need to COUNT clients considering 3 different other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have 2 different tables that I need to count how many new clients I have monthly, considering region and company size.

New clients are understood as having movement_type = 'new_biz'.
ID (Cust_Table) and OrgID (Org_table) are FKs.

ORG_TABLE

```
| OrgID  | OrgCreate  | Region        | CompanySize
│ 1   │ 2020-01-10 │ south america │ 51-100
│ 2   │ 2020-03-15    │  asia   │ 0 - 50
│ 3   │ 2020-01-12    │north america│ 1001-5000
│ 4   │ 2020-10-01    │ africa      │ 0 - 50
│ 5   │ 2020-06-30    │south america│ 5001-10000
```

CUST_TABLE

```
│ ID │  CreateAt  │  Movement_type
│ 1  │ 2020-01-10 │ new_biz
│ 2  │ 2020-03-01 │ churn
│ 3  │ 2020-01-12 │ new_biz
│ 4  │ 2020-10-01 │ new_biz
│ 5  │ 2020-06-12 │ expansion
```

The result I am trying to get is:

```
│ Month │ New_Clients │ Region │ Org_Size
│ 1   │  1  │ south america │ 51-100
│ 1   │  1  │ north america  │ 1001 - 5000
│ 10 │  1  │ africa  │ 0 - 50
```

I tried the following query, but can't get the amount of new customers right...

SELECT

MONTH(CreateAt) AS 'Month',

ID AS 'Client ID',

CompanySize AS 'Company Size',

Region AS 'Region'

FROM ORG_TABLE

JOIN CUST_TABLE ON org_id = ID

WHERE YEAR(CreateAt) = 2020 AND Movement_type = 'new_biz';

What am I missing? :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want aggregation:

```
SELECT MONTH(CreateAt) AS Month, COUNT(*) as new_clients
       CompanySize, Region 
FROM ORG_TABLE o JOIN
     CUST_TABLE c
     ON c.org_id = o.ID
WHERE c.CretedAt >= '2020-01-01' AND
      c.CreateAt < '2021-01-01' AND
      c.Movement_type = 'new_biz'
GROUP BY MONTH(CreateAt), CompanySize, Region
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Can you guide me through your thought process on why you chose to aggregate?

Comment: @E.A. . . . You seem to want the number of new clients in a month (subject to other conditions).  That seems like aggregation.